# How to change a specific symbol in a string

Tags: typescript

```
 let myDate= "10/10/2017";
 let re = /\//gi;
 myDate.replace(re, "-");
 console.log(myDate);
```

I have a string with a simple date and I need to change the "/"with "**-**", I know it may duplicate with other topics and I have read them arleady, but I just can't understand why it's not working.
My output is still:

```
"10/10/2017"
```

The looking result is:

```
"10-10-2017"
```

Comment: If you read about this already then how did you miss the first hit for a google search on the replace function?

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 1):

The `replace` creates a new string, so you need to assign the result to a variable:

```
myDate = myDate.replace(/\//g, '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

The strings are immutable, so you must use:

```
str = str.replace(re, '-')
```

Comment: well now it has changed only the first '/' with '-', not both of them

Comment: My bad, forgot to change the symbol with the RegEx :)